# External display detected but stays blank

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10 on an old Dell Latitude E6420 laptop and it works fine except when I attach an external 4k UHD display: Ubuntu seems to see it, but the display stays blank. This display works with my MacBook, but when I move the cable to my Dell, sadness.

Specifically, when I have Settings > Screen Display up and running, plugging in the HDMI cable causes the built-in display to flicker & break up, then reform with the Screen Display dialog showing the 2nd display called XXX 32" in the Primary Display drop-down and I can adjust the settings for XXX 32" (orientation, resolution, refresh rate, adjust for TV). But the display just shows "No Signal".

I move the HDMI cable back to Mac & I see what I expect on the display. And the Ubuntu Settings > Screen Display does the flicker & break up thing described above settling into a single Built-in display.

Can someone tell me where to look to troubleshoot this? I'm no Ubuntu or Linux expert, but I know enough to google what I can't grok.

Thanks in advance,

steve

Comment: This may not be germane, but I had some lock-up problems with this machine that I solved by installing the nVidia drivers. (Don't tell rms.) This made the 2nd display quit showing up when I plugged it in/turned it on. I suppose there's some Good Reason why this display cannot work that the nVidia drivers explicitly forbid while the open source drivers are a little more tolerant before disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the nVidia drivers and a reboot/power-cycle did indeed make the 2nd display become visible. It now detects as XXX 49" which is probably b/c the display is a Black Friday 50" TV purchase. It's amazing what we can get these days for cheap.

After I ran ubuntu-drivers to see what it could see, and what was recommended, I ran sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.

I hope this helps the next guy.